# Why doubly esc mapping not working with neovim + tmux?

Tags: tmux, neovim

I had the following mapping in my `.vimrc` to clear the search result highlight

`nnoremap<esc><esc> :noh<return>`

However, I noticed that this mapping does not work when I was using `neovim` + `tmux`.

My other mapping works totally fine, the weird thing is, this certain`<esc><esc>` does work when I was using `neovim` alone, and its also working with `vim8` + `tmux`.

Anyone knows what might be the problems here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -sg escape-time 0
```

**escape-time** time - Set the time in milliseconds for which tmux waits after an escape is input to determine if it is part of a function or meta key sequences. The default is 500 milliseconds.